# undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _auth.PhoneAuthProvider()')

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement Firebase phone auth in expo. Firebase is connected but its giving me error undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _auth.PhoneAuthProvider()')

```
//send verification code sms
  const sendVerificationCode = async () => {
    try {
      const phoneProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(); //giving error here
      console.log(phoneProvider);

      const id = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber,
        recaptchaVerifier.current
      );

      console.log(id);
      Alert.alert("Verification code has been sent to your phone.");
      navigation.navigate("Otp", {
        verificationId: id,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      // Alert.alert("Please enter a valid number.");
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: which version of firebase do you use? you could add the oacage.json.

Comment: also add the import statement for `PhoneAuthProvider`

Comment: @nima I was importing like `import { getAuth, PhoneAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';` as explained here https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-recaptcha/

Comment: @Frank Actually PhoneAuthProvider method was not exposed by firebase in version 9.1.2 That was creating this issue and has solved now in version 9.2.0. See the issue here https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/14780. Can't mark your answer

Comment: Great to hear the issue was solved in Expo @WahasAliMughal . Can you write up a self-answer for that, so others can more easily find it too?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneAuthProvider method was not exposed by firebase in version 9.1.2 That was creating this issue and has solved now in version 9.2.0. See the issue here github.com/expo/expo/issues/14780.